# core-dns says NXDOMAIN from query outside Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running **Kubernetes** with **coredns**. I can query the **coredns** only when i am inside the cluster.

**Coredns** resolves all `Pods` and `Service` from all `namespaces` fine:

```
pod1# nslookup pod99.svc.cluster.local 172.16.9.76 #(coredns)
```

Address 1: `172.16.8.99`

```
pod2# nslookup pod22.svc.cluster.local 172.16.9.76 #(coredns)
```

Address 2: `172.16.8.22`

and so on.

When I send the exact same query outside Kubernetes (from Home PC) I get:

```
HomePC# nslookup pod22svc.cluster.local 172.16.9.76 #(coredns)

** server can't find pod22.svc.cluster.local: NXDOMAIN
```

Log says:

```
1901 "A IN pod22.svc.cluster.local udp 47 false 512"
NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 140 0.000120622s
```

...so it is no Firewall or Routing Problem.

**Coredns** answers depends on the Source IP Address ????????

What is here the Problem ?

Comment: Is there anything else in `core-dns` logs apart from the mentioned fragment ? So it's never happening when you try to `nslookup` from any `Pod` or `node` ? What is your k8s version ?

Answer (score 1):

`svc.cluster.local` is resolved by CoreDNS which is running inside the kubernetes cluster. If you check `/etc/resolv.conf` inside any pod you will see IP of core dns pods.
Since there is no dns resolver outside the cluster which is aware of svc.cluster.local you can only access `svc.cluster.local` from inside the cluster.

Comment: Thank you. I'am query from outside the Cluster the Same coreDNS pod which is 172.16.9.76 .
My HomePC and Kubernetes are connected by VPN

Comment: Can you specifically tell what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to make DNS lookups from outside the Cluster. I want to know where are the Service currently running. With IP Addresses it is working but the IP Addresses change every new deployment